# Google Charts tutorial

Tags: google-app-engine, google-visualization

What is good place to learn about Google Charts apart from the the official Google web pages on the same subject (and various things you can do with charting libraries on the web beside Google)?

Are there any good sites on the same topic? I need to integrate an GAE app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several good tutorials on the web, I like [this short one](http://techtracer.com/2007/12/17/the-power-of-google-chart-api/) for example -- and note that, since the API is just about placing the right value in place of the `...` in an `<img src=”http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?...` in your HTML, there's nothing different about using it in GAE or in any other website or web app framework!-)

Answer (score 3):

how about "[Google Chart API - A Real World Example](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/web-20/google-chart-api-a-real-world-example)"?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same question!  I did find [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-graphs-with-google-chart-tools/), which seems to be more of what I've been looking for.